# ajax success return value complicated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working some corrections in one website,I am stuck in ajax success value I couldn't understand the return method can you explain it..

```
    success:function(e)
        {   
          return""!=e?
          ($("#emailid").parent().addClass("error"),
          $("#email").parent().removeClass("success"),
          alert(e),
          $("#buttoncss").attr("disabled","disabled"),!1):void $("#buttoncss").removeAttr("disabled")}}
```

can you guys how **return""!=e** is working want to know return"" what is that..

Comment: WHy did you tag this question PHP? Better tag it javascript and/or AJAX and/or JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you provided, the check is to ensure that some data has been returned upon successful completion of the AJAX request. `"" != e` evaluates to either `true` or `false` depending on if any data has been returned. What this is checking is that `e`, the data returned from the AJAX request, actually contains anything.

#### Ternary operator

This works just like an `if else` statement block.

```
if (foo > bar)
    return true;
else
    return false
```

Can be rewritten as

```
return foo > bar ? true : false;
```

After `"" != e` has been evaluated to `true` or `false`, the ternary operator is used just like above. Statements proceeding the `?` occur if the starter statement is `true` and statements proceeding the `:` occur if the starter statement is `false`. In other words, it could be rewritten as:

```
if("" != e){
   $("#emailid").parent().addClass("error"),
   $("#email").parent().removeClass("success"),
   alert(e),
   $("#buttoncss").attr("disabled","disabled"),!1);
   return true;
}

else{
    $("#buttoncss").removeAttr("disabled");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok got it scott thanks for giving the answer...

Comment: If you found this answer 'works' for you, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. You are under no obligation to do so, however.